# Is it "irgendjemand" or "irgend jemand"? One word or two?

Tags: indefinite-pronoun

My German class's lecture materials say that it's "irgend jemand" (two words), but every source I've come across online uses it as a single word (irgendjemand). The latter makes more sense—it's anybody, not "any body."

Which is correct? Are they both acceptable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct form is »irgendjemand«. This has been changed in the course of the ortography reform of 1996; before 1996, »irgend jemand« was the correct form. I guess that's the main reason why you see both, but nowadays one should write it as one word.

---

**Source:** The official rules from 1996 say:

> [§39] Mehrteilige Adverbien, Konjunktionen, Präpositionen und Pronomen schreibt man zusammen, wenn die Wortart, die Wortform oder die Bedeutung der einzelnen Bestandteile nicht mehr deutlich erkennbar sind.
>
> Dies betrifft
>
> [...]
>
> (4) Pronomen, zum Beispiel:
>
> *irgend-: irgendein, irgendetwas, irgendjemand, irgendwas, irgendwelcher, irgendwer*

(https://www.vbk.ac.at/files/docs_recht/public/Amtliche%20Regeln%20Neue%20deutsche%20Rechtschreibung%202006.pdf, pp. 41/42)

Additionally, in the word list they list *irgendjemand* and mark it with a star, indicating that this has indeed been changed by the reform (p. 160).